# How to find the Circle Collision Response

Tags: c++, game-physics, directx-9

I'm currently making a 2D pool game where i have to use real physics simulation. I have done the circle collision and elastic collision so far, But I want a formula which can find the collision response velocity, which differs when a ball collides with other at different points thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are many approaches, but if you can afford to make the balls overlap a bit (that is, to make part of the ball "enter" the other) you can turn it into a spring-damper system and solve with [Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law).

Since Hooke's law give you the force, you need to integrate it to find the momentum. Momentum divided by mass is the velocity you're looking for.

Take a look at [this](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/spring-physics/) excellent intro of spring physics for game development (that also has a link for his intro on numerical integration).

edit: if you're looking for a practical solution I suggest the [Box2D physics engine](http://box2d.org/).

Comment: No this is not actually what i meant, I want to find the collision response angle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Elastischer_sto%C3%9F_2D.gif

Comment: @user2028359 - Then you should change your question, because it says **"collision response velocity"**

Comment: @user2028359 I believe that with this approach you can extract the angle as well: it's the direction of the acceleration your physics engine calculate during the collision. If you divide the acceleration (or force) by its norm, you have the sine and cosine of the collision angle. There's a complication because the acceleration will vary during the collision (the collision is not instantaneous). Also note that with spring-damper systems you don't need to calculate angles directly (unless you want them for in-game logic).

Comment: I have implemented 2d collisions many times. Integration of Hooke's law is the best (fastest, most stable, and easiest to modify) method that I have found. It will also give you the velocity implicitly. You just split the Hooke's law force into components using trig, and add all of the vectors, each multiplied by an infinitesimal change in time and divided by the mass of the object to find the final velocity, also  in vector form.

Answer (score 0):

Pool collision can be considered as elastic collision throughout the board, with friction slowing down its movement.

Don;t think the collision response in terms of angles to the circle. Using vectors will ease the problem.

The circle-circle collision velocity response is easy:
1. When collision is detected
2. FInd the normal velocity of the balls acting toward the other ball.
3. Interchange the Normal velocity between the two balls
4. Resolve the velocity in x and y direction

A very helpful webiste to find the velocity response in terms of vectors: http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html